# Losing control, How could I reach this effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, effect

The main idea is to get some effect animating divs in my page. 
First, the main clues:

```
<ul class="institucional-menu">
            <li class="insmenu" id="Historia">Historia Fundacional</li>
            <li class="insmenu" id="Autoridades">Autoridades</li>
            <li class="insmenu" id="Balance">Balance</li>
        </ul>
```

When pointer is over some menu option, a div on the right moves and shows an image according to each option, which will be there until next user mouse movement over other different option. In the first action (the first user movement over some option) is ok, the problem begins from the second and higher actions, because the previous IMG is there, so I need to move the div to right ( creating the effect that it goes away to take another img) and return it from the right to the left with the new img charged inside.

Here is my Javascript:

```
jQuery('.insmenu').mouseover(function(){
        jQuery('#imgcontainer').animate({
            left: '1024px',
            opacity: '1'
        });
        jQuery('#imgcontainer').queue(function(){
            jQuery('#imgcontainer').attr("src", e.id+'.jpg');
            jQuery('#imgcontainer').animate({
            left: '0px',
            opacity: '1'
        });
        });
    });
```

I was trying all day long to first move away the dive, then charge image, and finally return that div. But I could not. Any recommendation?

Thank you very much!

PD: "e.id" tries to be the value of the element that has been "hovered" (I do not know how to say it, and if this verb exists) for example id="Historia", images have the same name like the ID value on each

That is why I am losing control, I was trying to pass that value...

Comment: I like this effects questions, can you continue this fiddle? so i can see what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/KLrVg/1/

Comment: what is `e.id`? and can you post the markup for `#imgcontainer`?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to erase that. I will correct it inmediately.

Comment: I am trying to complete the fiddle but it is not firing animate method, and I do not know why

Comment: Try with this version http://jsfiddle.net/KLrVg/22/ Note that the element can't be static to animate 'left'

Comment: `e.id` should likely be `e.attr("id")`

Comment: thank you, I will keep on doing tomorrow because my work time ended. Thank you, keep in contact for tomorrow please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.insmenu').mouseover(function(){
        var e = $(this);
        $('#imgcontainer').animate({
            left: '1024px',
            opacity: '1'
        },function(){
              $('#imgcontainer').attr("src",  e.attr('image'));
              console.log(e.attr('image'));
              $('#imgcontainer').animate({
                   left: '0px',
                   opacity: '1'
             });            
        });

    });
});
```

Please note that in order the left animation be posible, the item can't be static (change it's position to absolute, relative or fixed)

http://jsfiddle.net/KLrVg/22/

Comment: The images go away and come back. Thats what i understood you wanted, if not let me know. i changed the url image setting cause domain reasons. but you should be able to keep your way on that

Comment: this script moves the img, i could see it debugging with firbug, but for some reason it is not taking img

Comment: Thats what i said, i changed the url handling for the example

Comment: Thank you! It is working! But could you explain me what does this line mean?: **console.log(e.attr('image'));**. I do not know if I am a bad programmer, but I must say that I have never used that.

Comment: it's only to debug if the url was being loaded properly. it's like an alert('string') but les obstrusive, you can see it in the console of firebug, for example. you can delete it ;) By the way. if you found my answer helpfull mark is as correct :P

Answer (score 0):

I made this same effect on users' click instead of mouseover. Same idea, if I'm understanding correctly.

What I had to do was give each (here mouseover-able li) menu a div of its own inside the container div (here #imgcontainer). For example:

```
 <ul class="institucional-menu">
        <li class="insmenu" id="Historia">Historia Fundacional</li>
        <li class="insmenu" id="Autoridades">Autoridades</li>
        <li class="insmenu" id="Balance">Balance</li>
 </ul>
 <div id="imgcontainer">
    <div id="divHistoria><img src="..." /></div>
    <div id="divAuthoridades><img src="..." /></div>
    <div id="divBalance><img src="..." /></div>
 </div>
```

Then it's a simple matter of hiding/showing/animating the div with the same name as the menu item. No src swapping needed (although this could be an issue if there's a lot of very large images).

Comment: That is the problem. My images are 1024x768, so i was trying to avoid loading the hole set of images. But how could you solve the problem about hiding the previous div (with the animation two) and showing the new clicked one? That is my issue. It is complex to explain here...I think I will need a video

Comment: Try this. http://jsfiddle.net/KLrVg/25/  Feel free to change the animation as necessary, of course. Doesn't help with loading times, but is about what you need for swapping?

Comment: I was thinking about load times more: Either you'll need to load all of your images up front as part of the page loading, or as they mouseover your different sections. Being a person with slower internet, I was pretty confused in one of the previous jsFiddles because the image swapped but nothing showed - due to load times - so either way you should include some sort of loading indicator. It'l be run right away, or per each mouseover (unless img is cashed). I guess it depends on your setup, but I personally recommend once at first. Added time for some fancy loader/splash screen.